# NuxtLink is updating route in nuxt 3 app, but not rendering contents

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to use route using NuxtLink in a Nuxt 3 app, and it's changing the route, but it's not showing any contents. But, if I refresh or reload the updated route which was blank ago, then it's showing it's content normally.

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>It's Nuxt3!</h1>
    <p>Home Page</p>
  </div>
  <NuxtLink to="/user">User</NuxtLink>
</template>
```

`/pages/user.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>It's Nuxt3!</h1>
    <p>User Page</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Folder Structure & Illustration:

[image: Folder Structure]

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The console warning from Vue provides a helpful hint:

```
[Vue warn]: Component inside <Transition> renders non-element root node that cannot be animated. 
  at <Index onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< VueInstance > key="/" > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="page" mode="out-in" > 
  at <NuxtLayout key=0 name=undefined > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <App> 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

The log points to `<Index>` (i.e., `index.vue`), and we see that the [component there has two root nodes](https://github.com/iamsabbirsobhani/nuxt3-demo/blob/e11186b/pages/index.vue), which Vue wraps together in a fragment node, leading to the "non-element root node" warning:

```html
<template>
  <div> 1️⃣ <!-- root node -->
    <h1>Hello, World</h1>
    <p>It's Nuxt3!</p>
  </div>
  <NuxtLink to="/user">User</NuxtLink> 2️⃣ <!-- root node -->
</template>
```

Technically, this *should* be supported in Nuxt 3, which uses Vue 3, which supports multiple root nodes, but I'm not sure why that's not allowed in this scenario.

A workaround is to wrap the component's template with a single element, such as a `div`:

```html
// index.vue
<template>
  <div>  <!-- single root node -->
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, World</h1>
      <p>It's Nuxt3!</p>
    <div>
    <NuxtLink to="/user">User</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: As [written here](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages/#usage), this is something that is required to allow for proper animations. This is not a Nuxt limitation, because in [Vue's doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#the-transition-component), it also states `<Transition> only supports a single element or component as its slot content. If the content is a component, the component must also have only one single root element`, hence everything is as expected.

Comment: Even having commented code before the root node will break the rendering process!